# Avoid fetching image again when cell in view

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, alamofire, alamofireimage

I have managed to get some code working where Instagram pictures are fetched (via Alamofire) when a table row comes into view. However, once fetched, I don't want another call being made when the table row comes into view again. How can I avoid this behaviour?

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let url = places[indexPath.row].url
    if let c = cell as? PlaceTableViewCell {
        print("Downloading Image")
        Alamofire.request(url, method: .get).responseImage { response in
            guard let image = response.result.value else {
                print("Error downloading image")
                return
            }
            c.photoImageView.image = image
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way if you're already using `AlamoFire` is [`AlamoFireImage`](https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage). It has built in caching mechanisms you can use. For example:

```
let imageCache = AutoPurgingImageCache()

let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://httpbin.org/image/png")!)
let avatarImage = UIImage(named: "avatar")!.af_imageRoundedIntoCircle()

// Add
imageCache.add(avatarImage, for: urlRequest, withIdentifier: "circle")

// Fetch
let cachedAvatarImage = imageCache.image(for: urlRequest, withIdentifier: "circle")

// Remove
imageCache.removeImage(for: urlRequest, withIdentifier: "circle")
```

For your specific case we could do something simpler actually. AlamoFireImage contains a `UIImageView` extension tailored made for your need. This should load the image from a shared cache if its already been downloaded.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let url = places[indexPath.row].url
    if let c = cell as? PlaceTableViewCell {
        print("Downloading Image")
        c.photoImageView.af_setImage(withURL: url)
    }
}
```

You can also use some optional parameters for useful additional features like a placeholder image while the image loads or incase it fails to load.

```
c.photoImageView.af_setImage(withURL: url, placeholderImage: placeholderImage)
```

or a completion block

```
c.photoImageView.af_setImage(withURL: url, completion: { response in
    guard let image = response.result.value else {
        print("Error downloading image")
        return
    }
    c.photoImageView.image = image
})
```

Comment: shouldn't it be "https://httpbin.org/image.png" instead of "https://httpbin.org/image/png"

Comment: Btw. didn't know about AlamoFireImage, thanks for heads up :)

Comment: Would you mind showing me how to do what I've done but with AlamofireImage + cache. I tried it once myself but couldn't get it going for some reason

Comment: @Miknash actually it is `https://httpbin.org/image/png` in this case. Just the odd url of the test image haha.

Comment: Thanks for clarification :)

Comment: @tommyd456 I added an example using your code as the base.

Comment: Thanks but where do you actually use AlamofireImage?

Comment: `af_setImage(...)` is an AlamofireImage extension on UIImageView.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use some of third party libraries(e.g. https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher). That way, you will have cache for your images and won't have to download it again in the future.

However, if you don't want to hustle with more third party libraries, you could create array of images and after download put it into the array. Instantiate array for same size as your data array. Then, your code would look like:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let url = places[indexPath.row].url
    if let c = cell as? PlaceTableViewCell {
        print("Downloading Image")
        if let image = arrayOfImages[indexPath.row] {
            c.photoImageView.image = image
        }
        else {
            Alamofire.request(url, method: .get).responseImage { response in
                guard let image = response.result.value else {
                    print("Error downloading image")
                    return
                }
                c.photoImageView.image = image
                self.arrayOfImages[indexPath.row] = image
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this suggestion. Thanks

Comment: I guess the downside is that without a cache, all images would need to be retrieved again on app load?

Comment: That is correct - you would download them again when you get back to the screen. It is more temp cache then temporary one

Comment: Is your logic right? Don't you need to check for existence of image url in array? I can't see you doing that anywhere.

Comment: right below print("Downloading Image") - I save image